# Do other users see my answer even if I delete it?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)

As the heading states, Do other users see my answer even if I delete it? I never really understood it.

Comment: @Mat,@TimPost, A question that is barely 10% duplicate is closed as an exact duplicate.

Comment: @ahmedtabrez: I don't understand your comment. This question is answered in the FAQ linked. The fact that the FAQ has lots more information is irrelevant.

Comment: @Mat, but the faq is too subjective. This question is a one liner. Well, no problem now... anyhow the question is cosed...

Comment: @ahmedtabrez: FAQ is subjective? What do you mean by that? Do you really think we should split out each faq Q&A into as many Qs and As as there are lines in them? Consolidated doc is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes users with 10k rep see the answers even though it is deleted.

Comment: But we still can go though the edits history and look at original content. Or we cant?

Comment: yes you can still do that, if you want. The dashes just remove the answer from immediate viewing for 10k rep users

Comment: The dashes are considered content vandalism, and that's a suspension worthy offence.

Comment: @YannisRizos even for deleted answers? I am talking about the dashes in deleted answers not in actual content. If is a suspension worthy offense then there are a lot of high rep users on SO that would be suspended.

Comment: Yes. I don't think it's a rule that's often enforced on SO, however on SE 2.0 sites it is, defacing a post is _not_ a good habit, even if deleted. The reasoning is that even a deleted post can be edited and undeleted, and it should be available to reviewers at its best possible form. There's even a ready made suspension template for content defacement.

Comment: @YannisRizos well that is good to know I was not aware that it was  a suspension worthy offense. I will remove that as a part of my answer. Sorry for posting that

Comment: It's probably never enforced on SO because nobody flags deleted posts unless they want them restored. However, I'm not going to raise an eyebrow if someone deletes their own answer and replaces it with something like 'Totally missed the point of the question' or 'Shucks, someone beat me to it', etc. The content is still there if it's needed, and I'm not going to force someone to leave an embarrassing answer out on display for everyone with 10k :)

Comment: If I decide to remove an answer within the initial grace period, I usually deface it as well. It may not be polite, but I don't really care and it's not like others can do anything about it.

Comment: Deleted answers aren't visible to the majority of people that visit the site to begin with @lunboks, it's quite a bit different from rage quitting and defacing all your stuff that _everyone_ can see.

Comment: @TimPost thanks for the explanation.  I always wondered about it, there are sometimes I answer quickly (not fully reading the question during a multi-task moment) only to want to plant my head in the ground when I realize how far off I was.  And then I know that my poor answer is still around and think 'Doh I am dumb today let me give back my nerd card'

Comment: @bluefeet We have a hard enough time policing _visible_ content on SO. We're not going to lose sleep over what someone does with content that has been deleted. Don't worry about it :)